# How to remove a file from the git index

Tags: git

How do I remove a file from a git repositorie's **index** without removing the file from the working tree?

If I had a file `./notes.txt` that was being tracked by git, I could run `git rm notes.txt`. But that would remove the file. I'd rather want git just to stop tracking the file.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You could just use `git rm --cached notes.txt`. This will keep the file but remove it from the index.

Answer (score 3):

`git reset HEAD <file>` for removing a particular file.

and `git reset HEAD` for removing all files from the git index.

Comment: That answer appeared 8 years after Gert's solution, has semantic of `git reset` command changed since that time?

Answer (score 0):

`git restore --staged <file>` worked fine for me